# confusion writing self join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to write a SQL query and I am confused either I can solve it by self join or using an inner query.

I have a table containing columns

```
UserID, DateSubscription, Status
```

`Status` can be `'E'` or `'R'`.

I have to select users that has `subscription Date between Date1 and Date2` and that `UserID` should not load who have `Status = 'E'` and is not in Date Range between `Date1` And `Date2`.

`UserID` can exist in multiple rows with different status

Below is the query i tried

```
SELECT  
       IDNO,
       IND_ID,
       IND_SRC,
       EXPIRY_DATE,
       RECSTA
FROM 
      VIND,
      VSCR
WHERE 
      VIND.IND_ID = VSCR.IND_ID
AND   
      VIND.IND_SRC = VSCR.IND_SRC  
AND 
      EXPIRY_DATE >= '2015-04-25'
AND 
      EXPIRY_DATE <= '2015-06-25'

AND
( 
          RECSTA <> 'E'
      AND
          EXPIRY_DATE > '2015-06-25'
)
```

Comment: can you include what you have tried so far?

Comment: Ughi I tried sub query but it was useless then tried same query as two answer below but it do not fetch any record

Comment: Its always better to post sample data and expected output as well. you'll get faster and more accurate answers.

Comment: You query will never return a result... you are saying "_I want all records where the expiry date is between 2015-04-25 and 2015-06-25 and also where the expiry date is greater than 2015-06-25_" - there are no dates that satisfy all those conditions, so you'll never get anything back. I don't think you need the final `AND` (i.e. everything in the brackets at the end)

Comment: But i don't need records that has status E in other dates.

Comment: Oh right - I think I understand your question now. It was a bit open to interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want all records where the expiry date is between A and B, and also all records outside this date where the status is NOT `E`

```
select *
  from yourtable
 where EXPIRY_DATE between @startDateParam and @endDateParam
   or  [Status] <> 'E'
```

Comment: Actually I think your problem statement can be interpreted in a number of ways. Can you confirm if you want all users with a subscription between Date1 and Date2, or just those where the status is R?

Comment: I need all subscriptions between say Date1 and Date2 regardless of the status but want to exclude the results that are Greater than Date2 AND Status equals to 'E'.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
select UserID, DateSubscription
from table
where DateSubscription between @startDate and @endDate and 
(Status <> 'E'  OR  DateSubscription not between @startDate and @endDate)
```

Comment: I tried this query before but it produce no result may be due to conflict between date range condition on two places

Comment: Did u used brackets properly?

Comment: I have changed the answer. Try that

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `NOT EXISTS`to check the second requirement

```
SELECT
    UserID
FROM
    Subscriptions
WHERE
    DateSubscription BETWEEN @date1 and @date2
AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT
       NULL
    FROM
        Subscriptions OtherSubscriptions 
    WHERE
        -- Get UserIDs other rows 
        Subscriptions.UserID = OtherSubscriptions.UserID
        -- Only rows that have status 'E'
    AND OtherSubscriptions.Status = 'E'
        -- subscription is before @date1 or after @date2
    AND (OtherSubscriptions.DateSubscription < @date1
        OR OtherSubscriptions.DateSubscription > @date2)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to `group by` on  `userid` and filter the data using `HAVING` and `CASE`.

```
SELECT UserID, DateSubscription, Status
FROM UserStatusTable
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN DateSubscription BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1
AND SUM(CASE WHEN DateSubscription NOT BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2 AND Status = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```